# why do we need to install gatsby-plugin-styled-components after installed styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, gatsby

I'm learning Gatsbyjs and saw an odd thing.

For example, if I want to use styled-components, I need to install:
gatsby-plugin-styled-components
AND
styled-components

Whereas, I tried to only install styled-components and it works.

My question is:

Why do I need to install related Gatsbyjs plugin in this case?

Comment: many react packages "work" in gatsby without gatsby-plugins but not all in an optimal way. Gatsby plugins mostly take care of gatsby dev/build environment config (e.g. gatsby/webpack/babel config). Styled components gatsby plugin does this by modification of gatsby-ssr.js and gatsby-node.js [source](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-styled-components/src).

Comment: Thanks @AndreasT  could you please share some links to the details documentations please?

Comment: Also, as Gatsbyjs is a static website generator, why do I need the ssr support for styled-components library???

Comment: Unfortunately there are no detailed docs for styled-components gatsby-plugin (and many other plugins) but you can check the github repo(source) i linked. Gatsby uses SSR to "transform" react app(JS) to static pages (HTML). This happens on `gatsby build` command. The "server" at that case is at your `/public` directory. Gatsby SSR is not exactly the same as typical SSR but it works the same way - develop (react)JS, serve HTML- and is one of it's core features.

Comment: Cool, thanks. It starts to make sense now.

Answer (score 16):

The answer is that just using `styled-components` will result in `styled-components` being applied on client JavaScript runtime. So sometimes, when you load your Gatsby site, you will see the styles you've written with `styled-components`-components not immediately on your website but they will be applied after some delay which can result in some weird visual effect (elements jumping around, or changing in color / size / other properties).

`gatsby-plugin-styled-components` makes sure the styles will be delivered to the client right from the HTML.

Comment: For clarity, in order for Gatsby to know what static assets to generate (and what will be shown on page load) there needs to be something that tells it how to handle `styled-components` and what to display because of them. Otherwise, this happens after page load, as mentioned.

Comment: So basically we need it for ssr?